# Mark all old reminders "done" in Inbox by Gmail

Tags: gmail, inbox-by-gmail

I have hundreds of old reminders that I created in the past year with Google Now that are now pinned in my "Inbox" (http://inbox.google.com).

I would like to mark all of them as "done".

I can select them one by one, is there a way to select them all? or at least several at a time?

Comment: @pnuts sorry, don't understand what is the problem.

Comment: it used to be! now works on any desktop with Google Chrome ;) also the main topic in the question is "Inbox": http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2014/10/an-inbox-that-works-for-you.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Might take a little while (depending on how many you have... and how the refresh of the screen works etc)... but show the pinned items, and hold down `[` on your keyboard.

You need to have "Keyboard Shortcuts" on. Click on the 3 lines in top left, then scroll to the bottom, click Settings, Under "Other", tick "Keyboard Shortcuts".

Comment: Awesome! I wiped all of them out, thanks.

Answer (score 13):

Inbox's treatment of "Done" is the same as Gmail's "Archived". So whatever gets "Archived" in Gmail will be marked as "Done" in Inbox. As such, you can leverage Gmail's bulk editing to have it show in Inbox. Simply mark what you want in Gmail, either by filters, multiple selection etc. and then mark it as "Archived" which will make them marked as "Done" in Inbox. This is how I was able to mark my 16,000 unread emails in Gmail as "Done" in Inbox.

Comment: +1 Thanks, this is useful for emails, unfortunately it won't work with reminders.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use some automation extensions like [iMacros](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/imacros-for-chrome/cplklnmnlbnpmjogncfgfijoopmnlemp?hl=en) if you're using Google Chrome.